# How to create a object of class which include embed class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The class MySettings include two embed class in Code A, how can I create a oject of MySettings ?
It seems that `fun initA()` can't instance of two embed class.

I realize that the construct of Code A is wrong, so I write Code B, I don't know whether there is a good way!

**Code A**

```
class MySettings(val _id: Long) {

    data class MyBluetooth(
            val status: Boolean = false
    )

    data class WiFiDef(
            val name: String,
            val status: Boolean = false
    )
}


fun initA(){
  var myObject =MySettings(10L)
}
```

**Code B**

```
class MySettings(val _id: Long) {
   var aMyBluetooth: MyBluetooth? =null
   var aWiFiDef: WiFiDef?=null
}


data class MyBluetooth(
            val status: Boolean = false
 )

data class WiFiDef(
            val name: String,
            val status: Boolean = false
)


fun initB(){
   var myObject =MySettings(10L)
   myObject.aMyBluetooth=MyBluetooth(false)
   myObject.aWiFiDef=WiFiDef("name",true)
}
```

Comment: Code B looks better. There's no reason your `MyBluetooth` and `WiFiDef` class definitions need to be coupled to the definition of `MySettings`. Imagine if you make a `MySettings2` and want to re-use some of the components. Code B lets you do this far easier. As a generality, the simpler you make your components, and the less dependency they have on eachother, the better.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your question is concerned **Code A** is absolutely right.

But if we draw a comparison between your **Code A** and **Code B**, there are different scenarios in which they are best suited.

**Scenario 1: Good Programming Practice**

If you want to follow good programming practice in Kotlin, then follow Code B as it is a good practice to write code that is reusable. And one more thing, you can instantiate your object in code B like this.

```
fun initB(){
    var myObject =MySettings(10L, aMyBluetooth=MyBluetooth(false), 
                             aWiFiDef=WiFiDef("name",true))
}
```

**Scenario 2: Inner Class**

Your Code A is useful in a situation where you want to implement inner class in kotlin. Inner class is able to access members of outer class. But in this scenario, data class cannot be inner.

```
class MySettings(val _id: Long) {

    inner class MyBluetooth(
            val status: Boolean = false
    )

    inner class WiFiDef(
            val name: String,
            val status: Boolean = false
    )
}


fun initA(){
  var myObject =MySettings(10L)
}
```

I hope this clears your query.

Comment: Thanks! but in Code B, your code `var myObject =MySettings(10L, aMyBluetooth=MyBluetooth(false), 
                             aWiFiDef=WiFiDef("name",true))` don't work!

Comment: Sorry, I forget to write. You also have to  declare the same parameters in Class declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your data classes inside MySettings if you combine somehow Code A and Code B:

```
class MySettings(val _id: Long) {
    val blueTooth = MyBluetooth(true)
    val wiFiDef = WiFiDef("wifi", true)

    data class MyBluetooth(
            val status: Boolean = false
    )

    data class WiFiDef(
            val name: String,
            val status: Boolean = false
    )
}


fun initA(){
    val myObject = MySettings(10L)
    val myBlueTooth = myObject.blueTooth
    val myWiFiDef = myObject.wiFiDef
}
```

After that it's up to you to decide by changing all or any of `val` to `var` inside `MySetings` how to use the instances of the data classes. But this is a way to expose them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with approach like this:

1. Make use of Kotlin constructors, which can take class-scope variables. Just mark those nullable (via `?`) inside constructor and let the user decide wether he/she wants to initialise those variables or not
2. Make all settings (bluetooth and wifi) extend from sealed class, especially since you have common variables between them.

To sum up, I would write this code like this:

```
class MySettings(val id: Long, val bluetooth: Setting.MyBluetooth? = null, val wifi: Setting.WifiDef? = null) {

    sealed class Setting(val status: Boolean = false) : Serializable {
        class WifiDef(
                status: Boolean,
                val name: String
        ): Setting(status)

        class MyBluetooth(
                status: Boolean
        ): Setting(status)
    }
}

fun init() {
    val mySettings = MySettings(10L, bluetooth = MySettings.Setting.MyBluetooth(true))
    val bluetooth = mySettings.bluetooth
    val wifi = mySettings.wifi
}
```

Talking about other ways to do this, I would highly recommend not to hard code any values inside your class, especially not when you have some instances of classes inside. This will be hideous to refactor later on, if something changes